# How to change hotkeys

Tags: starcraft

In Starcraft/BroodWar is there a way to change the default hotkeys? I'm almost completely sure that there is no way in-game to change them. But is there a mod or any 3rd party software that can modify them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None that I've ever heard of and I've spent quite a lot of time playing the game.

You can modify your client and change the hotkeys but that will render you unable to play with anyone else who doesn't have the exact same mod.

Comment: At least with some techniques, modding your hotkeys doesn't prevent you from playing with others. I think even a straight forward modification of the mpq file shouldn't cause issues - after all each language version of starcraft has its own hotkeys.